# Graph Viewer option available in WPF UI?

Tags: .net, wpf, reporting-services

In a WPF UI app, is there any control to display graph?

I mean, i have 2 combo boxes, on selecting the values in it, it generates a graph.( I have done this using crystal report viewer in a normal windows app... ).

How to achevie this in WPF?? As a  is available for documents, do WPF has any graph or reports viewer in it.

I am not using SilverLight. So, only wpf controls if available needs to be used.

Please guide me.
Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The July 2009 release of the [WPF Toolkit on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf) includes chart controls, I have heard good things about them.  These are free, Microsoft-developed chart controls.  You download the package and install it and it will add the controls to your Visual Studio installation.

There are also numerous third-party chart libraries that provide charts and graphs, both commercial and open-source.

Comment: What XAML Control needs to be added to view the report in WPF app?
I have done in windows.forms app, where I was able to create a report in USER CONTROL. But how to show it in WPF XAML? 
I mean include a ListBox and add item to it??
Please guide me.
Thanks
Ramm